Nuxt-i18n: Disable seo alternate headers added by `nuxt-i18n` in Nuxt-3
My issue is that I want to disable autogenerared link that are automatically generated by nuxt-i18n v8.5.5.
Unfortunately, useHead() cannot directly override the tags generated.
I have tried adding middleware on the server side since my application uses SSR, as well as on the client side with a plugin, but nothing seems to work. The x-default alternate link with the ID i18n-xd always remains.
<link id="i18n-xd" rel="alternate" href="..." hreflang="x-default">
<meta id="i18n-og-url" property="og:url" content="...">

